# How to handle exceptions in junit?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit4, junit5

I have this method which is negative test case and it will fail when some sort of file doesnt exist ,

```
@Test
    @DisplayName("Negative test Case when  tab doesnt exist ,Expected Exception")
    public void tabDoesntExist() throws Exception {
        Data gs = new Data(propertyFile, outsourceFolder);
        Exception exception = assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> gs.processWorkbook(filelist));
        assertTrue(exception.getMessage().contains("null"));
    }
```

but as of now the file is existing and no exception will be thrown so how can we handle that , as of now its giving something like this  , any sort of help is appreciated .

```
Expected java.lang.Exception to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Expected java.lang.Exception to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
at com.planlytx.aggrid.GenDropdownJsonTest.inputFileDoesntExist(GenDropdownJsonTest.java:93)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Comment: TBH this test looks absolutely fine to me. The message you posted indicates that the `assertThrows` was false. You expected an exception but non was thrown. Isn't that the behavior you described?

Comment: It looks like the output is from a different test: GenDropdownJsonTest.inputFileDoesntExist

Answer (score 1):

In your test you did not call the actual method, which you are testing. Hence no exception is thrown.

Replace,

```
Exception exception = assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> gs.processWorkbook(filelist));
```

with

```
when(gs.processWorkbook(filelist)).thenThrow(new Exception());
```

**Update:**
If you method is returning void in that case you can use below syntax.

```
doThrow(new Exception()).when(gs).processWorkbook(filelist);
```

Comment: method returns void  so it doesnt work , The method when(T) in the type Mockito is not applicable for the arguments (void)

Comment: Updated the answer.